# ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax - Cannot understand what the error means

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I'm trying to import an SQL db, exported from another place. I have the SQL create script. I am not sure what might be going wrong...

My mariadb version is

```
select version();
+----------------+
| version()      |
+----------------+
| 10.5.8-MariaDB |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.000 sec)
```

Table create script:

```
-- phpMyAdmin SQL Dump
-- version 5.0.4
-- https://www.phpmyadmin.net/
--
-- Host: db
-- Generation Time: Jan 04, 2021 at 05:59 PM
-- Server version: 8.0.22
-- PHP Version: 7.4.11

SET SQL_MODE = "NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";
START TRANSACTION;
SET time_zone = "+00:00";


/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT=@@CHARACTER_SET_CLIENT */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS=@@CHARACTER_SET_RESULTS */;
/*!40101 SET @OLD_COLLATION_CONNECTION=@@COLLATION_CONNECTION */;
/*!40101 SET NAMES utf8mb4 */;

--
-- Database: `mytestdb`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mytestdb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
USE `mytestdb`;

-- --------------------------------------------------------

--
-- Table structure for table `categories`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `categories`;
CREATE TABLE `categories` (
  `id` int NOT NULL,
  `category` varchar(100) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`json`,_utf8mb4'$.category'))) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `popular` enum('true','false') GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`json`,_utf8mb4'$.popular'))) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `imageUrl` varchar(255) GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(json_extract(`json`,_utf8mb4'$.imageUrl'))) VIRTUAL NOT NULL,
  `json` json NOT NULL,
  `timestamp` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

**Error**:

```
ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 33: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'NOT NULL,
  `popular` enum('true','false') GENERATED ALWAYS AS (json_unquote(...' at line 3
```

Comment: what you are trying is only allowed in MySQL 8.0.x and **not** in Mariadb

Comment: What version of MySQL/MariaDB are you trying to load _into_?

Comment: @RickJames I have it in the question - 10.5.8-MariaDB

Comment: For Mariadb, NOT NULL is not accepting for VIRTUAL columns. Please try after removing **NOT NULL**. 

https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/03/04/virtual-columns-in-mysql-and-mariadb/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not an expert in Mariadb but I think you cannot do it. From the [documentation on generated columns](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/generated-columns/)

> Generated columns can be referenced in the INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE statements.
> However, **VIRTUAL or PERSISTENT generated columns cannot be explicitly set to any other values than NULL or DEFAULT.** If a generated column is explicitly set to any other value, then the outcome depends on whether strict mode is enabled in sql_mode. If it is not enabled, then a warning will be raised and the default generated value will be used instead. If it is enabled, then an error will be raised instead.